# Taking means of irregular amounts data

Tags: excel

I'm not able to take the means for a large dataset given that the amount of attributes is irregular.

I have posted a simplified case for the problem. It explains the problem very well.
An idea that I came up with: Make a filter to condition on a single attribute. However, still, I don't see a way to do this in an efficient way (other then doing it all by hand).

see excel file: [image: Test problem]

All help is much appreciated.

I'm basically looking for a function/method to achieve taking means of all different attributes conditioned on each person for a large dataset without doing it by hand.

Comment: A very insightful remark! I posted a picture instead. Thank you.

Comment: If I understood your question correctly, a pivot table might suit you needs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use AVERAGEIFS() inside an IF:

```
=IF(OR(A2<>A1,B2<>B1),AVERAGEIFS(C:C,A:A,A2,B:B,B2),"")
```

the ifrst part of the if tests whether the row starts a new group either by the person or the attribute changing.  Then it uses `AVERAGEIFS()` to return the correct average of that group.  otherwise it returns a blank

[image: ![![enter image description here]

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm a novice with Excel, so I'm having a hard time understanding what you wrote down. Would you mind to provide a brief elaboration/explanation?

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do can be accomplished very simply with a pivot table.
Simply select one of the cells inside the range of data you want to process(See the video for general use of a pivot table https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iCiayB6GrpQ )
go the insert tab and insert pivot table.
Once you have it, simply check people, attribute, and values. Then drag people and attribute into rows, drag valut into the values window, select the drop down list and change it from sum of value to average and you should be done. https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYEzw.png